# Get last part of current URL in Laravel 5 using Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

How to get the last part of the current URL without the `/` sign, dynamically?

For example:

In `www.news.com/foo/bar`   get `bar`.

In `www.news.com/foo/bar/fun` get `fun`.

Where to put the function or how to implement this in the current view?

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_current and do a regex to get the part

Comment: Thanks, could you give me an example?

Comment: if you post examle code with what you came up with i will help you.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Of course there is always the Laravel way:

```
request()->segment(count(request()->segments()))
```

Comment: My first thought exactly, one line of code ;-) simple to understand

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 45):

You can use Laravel's helper function `last`. Like so:

`last(request()->segments())`

Answer (score 29):

This is how I did it:

```
{{ collect(request()->segments())->last() }}
```

Answer (score 20):

Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) along with `Request::path()`.

```
basename(request()->path())
```

You should be able to call that from anywhere in your code since `request()` is a global helper function in Laravel and `basename()` is a standard PHP function which is also available globally.

Answer (score 9):

The [Route object](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) is the source of the information you want. There are a few ways that you can get the information and most of them involve passing something to your view. I strongly suggest not doing the work within the blade as this is what controller actions are for.

**Passing a value to the blade**

The easiest way is to make the last part of the route a parameter and pass that value to the view.

```php
// app/Http/routes.php
Route::get('/test/{uri_tail}', function ($uri_tail) {
    return view('example')->with('uri_tail', $uri_tail);
});

// resources/views/example.blade.php
The last part of the route URI is <b>{{ $uri_tail }}</b>.
```

Avoiding route parameters requires a little more work.

```php
// app/Http/routes.php
Route::get('/test/uri-tail', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $route = $request->route();
    $uri_path = $route->getPath();
    $uri_parts = explode('/', $uri_path);
    $uri_tail = end($uri_parts);

    return view('example2')->with('uri_tail', $uri_tail);
});

// resources/views/example2.blade.php
The last part of the route URI is <b>{{ $uri_tail }}</b>.
```

**Doing it all in the blade** using the [request helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request).

```php
// app/Http/routes.php
Route::get('/test/uri-tail', function () {
    return view('example3');
});

// resources/views/example3.blade.php
The last part of the route URI is <b>{{ array_slice(explode('/', request()->route()->getPath()), -1, 1) }}</b>.
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `request()->segment($number)` it should give you a segment of the URL.

In your example, it should probably be `request()->segment(2)` or `request()->segment(3)` based on the number of segments the URL has.

Answer (score 2):

YourControllor:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

file.blade.php:

echo basename(URL::current());

Answer (score 1):

It was useful for me:

```
request()->path()
```

from www.test.site/news

get -> news

Comment: the simplest solution so far

Comment: This sometimes returns an extra part of the link:  example/blabla instead of blabla

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question. In the meantime Laravel 8. I have summarised all the possibilities I know.

You can test it in your web route:

1. http(s)://127.0.0.1:8000/bar/foo || baz
2. http(s)://127.0.0.1:8000/bar/bar1/foo || baz

```
Route::get('/foo/{lastPart}', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $lastPart) {
    dd(
        [
            'q' => request()->segment(count(request()->segments())),
            'b' => collect(request()->segments())->last(),
            'c' => basename(request()->path()),
            'd' => substr( strrchr(request()->path(), '/'), 1),
            'e' => $lastPart,
        ]
    )->where('lastPart', 'foo,baz'); // the condition is only to limit
```

I prefer the variant e).

As @Qevo had already written in his answer. You simply make the last part part of the request. To narrow it down you can put the WHERE condition at the route.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
{{ array_pop(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) }}
```

It should work well.

Comment: Also add a rtrim to remove the last slash if needed.